# Count values showing up more than once

Tags: sql

Here's what we have:

A login table: `(user_id, time_of_login)`

Here's what we're trying to query:

1. Number of users who logged in ONLY ONCE :
2. Number of users who logged in MORE THAN ONCE :

Example : 
user1 4:29PM
user2 4:29PM
user3 4:29PM
user1 4:29PM
user2 4:29PM
user5 4:29PM
user6 4:29PM

- Number of repeated users : 2
- Number of New Users : 3

we hope this helped

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: GROUP BY, COUNT, HAVING...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_id, count(*)
from table
group by user_id
having count(*)=1
```

and next:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from table
group by user_id
having count(*)>1
```

Comment: You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

logged in once:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS nr_of_logins
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING nr_of_logins = 1
```

logged in more than once:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS nr_of_logins
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING nr_of_logins > 1
```

Note: I did not test this.

Comment: Not valid ANSI SQL.